# Can't change DrawerLayout Icon even if Icon has been set in ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-actionbar, drawerlayout, actionbardrawertoggle

I just created a template project in Android Studio and I did not change a line of code (DrawerLayout template project).

However, I found the clicked icon for showing the navigation fragment is always a left arrow, even though in the code it sets the icon to another one.

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code for constructing ActionBarDrawerToggle:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        )
```

here's the png file for ic_drawer

[image: icon]

How do I change the DrawerLayout Icon?

Comment: Can you try to clean your project and then run?

Comment: sorry....its not working..

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, I have always seen the left arrow icon. 
I have solved in this way:

I noticed that android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle class has been deprecated, following some answers and from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar,%20int,%20int)), in my NavigationDrawerFragment class I have used

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(  getActivity(),                   
                                            mDrawerLayout,                    
                                            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  
                                            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  
                                    ) { ... }
```

Now it's OK, the icon makes a transition to arrow only when the Navigation Drawer appears.

Comment: seems like you are missing something from the constructor? where's your toolbar? so you set Icon in toolbar or what?

Answer (score 1):

Adding on the solution given by Anchor. I managed to make mine work by changing this import

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

to

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

Doing so will prompt you an error in the constructor of ActionBarDrawerToggle. Remove the R.drawable.ic_drawer so that it becomes:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    )
```

It should work now